# How to change columns order in generated table (grails constraints not working with mongodb plugin)

Tags: mongodb, grails, scaffolding

I'm using Grails 2.1.1 with mongodb plugin. I have problem with changing order of columns in generated list. As [grails scaffolding guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) says you need only properly order attributes in contraints block.

My domain:

```
class Section {

String idName
String visible
String required
String name
String bold

static embedded = ['question']

List<Question> questions
static hasMany = [questions : Question]

static constraints = {
    idName (blank: false)
    name (blank: false)
    visible (blank: false)
    required (blank: false)
    bold (blank: false)
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    name
}
}
```

but columns are still ordered alphabetically. I'm using static scaffolding, so after changes in constraints i use `grails generate-all *` command and override all files.

And yes, I tried cleaning and compiling code, also cleaning and restarting server (this integrated with STS) and cleaning browser cache. Is there problem with mongo database (hibernate plugin is uninstalled)?

After that I also installed grails templates. In list.gsp there is line with sorting attributes:

```
Collections.sort(props, comparator.constructors[0].newInstance([domainClass] as Object[]))
```

Any idea how can i change this to get working order that I set in constraints?

Comment: I started new grails project with the same environment (but without changing to mongodb) and ordering by constraints worked. So I'm almost sure it's problem with uninstalling hibernate plugin and/or installing mongodb plugin. I'll check it and give answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jira issue should be filled.  If one looks at 
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-crud/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/scaffolding/DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator.groovy

```
 void generateView(GrailsDomainClass domainClass, String viewName, Writer out) {
    def templateText = getTemplateText("${viewName}.gsp")

    if (templateText) {
        def t = engine.createTemplate(templateText)
        def multiPart = domainClass.properties.find {it.type == ([] as Byte[]).class || it.type == ([] as byte[]).class}

        boolean hasHibernate = pluginManager?.hasGrailsPlugin('hibernate')
        def packageName = domainClass.packageName ? "<%@ page import=\"${domainClass.fullName}\" %>" : ""
        def binding = [pluginManager: pluginManager,
                packageName: packageName,
                domainClass: domainClass,
                multiPart: multiPart,
                className: domainClass.shortName,
                propertyName:  getPropertyName(domainClass),
                renderEditor: renderEditor,
                comparator: hasHibernate ? DomainClassPropertyComparator : SimpleDomainClassPropertyComparator]

        t.make(binding).writeTo(out)
    }

}
```

It is clear that the call generate views decides to use SimpleDomainClassPropertyComparator.  Grails was originally built to depend on hibernate.  Over the last couple of years, the world has been using additional persistance mechanisms.   If one looks at DomainClassPropertyComparator, there is no dependency on hibernate.  I feel the code should test if the domainObject "hasConstraints" to decide which comparator to use or simple use DomainClassPropertyComparator by default.  Its behavior is the same if no constraints are found.  The call to "hasHibernate" should not be needed by DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator.

As a work around, you can install the scaffolding templates, edit _form.gsp and change the comparator it is using to DomainClassPropertyComparator 
e.g. my _form.gsp

```
    <%=packageName%>
<% import grails.persistence.Event %>
<% import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.DomainClassPropertyComparator %>


<%  excludedProps = Event.allEvents.toList() << 'version' << 'dateCreated' << 'lastUpdated'
    persistentPropNames = domainClass.persistentProperties*.name
    boolean hasHibernate = pluginManager?.hasGrailsPlugin('hibernate')
    if (hasHibernate && org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(domainClass)?.identity?.generator == 'assigned') {
        persistentPropNames << domainClass.identifier.name
    }

DomainClassPropertyComparator mattsComparator = new DomainClassPropertyComparator(domainClass)
comparator = mattsComparator

props = domainClass.properties.findAll { persistentPropNames.contains(it.name) && !excludedProps.contains(it.name) }
    Collections.sort(props, comparator)
    for (p in props) {
        if (p.embedded) {
            def embeddedPropNames = p.component.persistentProperties*.name
            def embeddedProps = p.component.properties.findAll { embeddedPropNames.contains(it.name) && !excludedProps.contains(it.name) }
            Collections.sort(embeddedProps, comparator)
            %><fieldset class="embedded"><legend><g:message code="${domainClass.propertyName}.${p.name}.label" default="${p.naturalName}" /></legend><%
                for (ep in p.component.properties) {
                    renderFieldForProperty(ep, p.component, "${p.name}.")
                }
            %></fieldset><%
        } else {
            renderFieldForProperty(p, domainClass)
        }
    }

private renderFieldForProperty(p, owningClass, prefix = "") {
    boolean hasHibernate = pluginManager?.hasGrailsPlugin('hibernate')
    boolean display = true
    boolean required = false
    if (hasHibernate) {
        cp = owningClass.constrainedProperties[p.name]
        display = (cp ? cp.display : true)
        required = (cp ? !(cp.propertyType in [boolean, Boolean]) && !cp.nullable && (cp.propertyType != String || !cp.blank) : false)
    }
    if (display) { %>
<div class="fieldcontain \${hasErrors(bean: ${propertyName}, field: '${prefix}${p.name}', 'error')} ${required ? 'required' : ''}">
    <label for="${prefix}${p.name}">
        <g:message code="${domainClass.propertyName}.${prefix}${p.name}.label" default="${p.naturalName}" />
        <% if (required) { %><span class="required-indicator">*</span><% } %>
    </label>
    ${renderEditor(p)}
</div>
<%  }   } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you comment the line below in the template and regenerate the view, the order in the constraints will be the order in scaffolding

```
//Collections.sort(props, comparator.constructors[0].newInstance([domainClass] as Object[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The contraints should update the view as you have described. Try running `grails generate-all --stacktrace` It's possible that the script terminates before updating the views accordingly. Another strategy would be to check whether the problem lies within the statements below, so getting rid of them and checking if the views update accordingly will probably bring you closer to solving your problem.

```
static embedded = ['question']

List<Question> questions
static hasMany = [questions : Question]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Option `--stacktrace` doesn't give any more information, but I'm sure script ends correctly because after changing fields in domains views are updated in gsp files. For these "other statements" from my domain, I created new simple domain in my project for testing scaffolding:

`class Simple {
 String zzz
 String kkk
 String aaa
 
    static constraints = {
  kkk()
  zzz()
  aaa()
    }
}`

but after generating new views order of columns and fields in gsp pages are still alphabetical. I think it's more about configuration or this mongodb plugin than just my domain definition.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I'm sure that using only mongodb plugin without hibernate plugin cause disabling some scaffolding features. For example constraints clause is omited during generating views. To make this work you need to use hibernate.
So if you want to have autogenerated code and still use mongodb there is a trick:
create, generate and finish project with hibernate, then for production uninstall hibernate and install mongodb.